# ODBC Query Works in MS Access But Times-Out in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, amazon-redshift, linked-server

We have a pass-through query in MS Access that we need to convert to SQL Server.

The query in MS Access is using a 32-bit ODBC DSN to connect to a Redshift database. The query is complex (e.g. has about 20 sub-queries), but runs fine in MS Access within 1 to 2 minutes.

We converted that query to SQL Server and use a Linked Server connection using a 64-bit ODBC DSN with the MSDASQL provider to connect to that same database. The query in SQL Server will try to run for over 30 minutes but then eventually times-out.

Any idea why it would work in MS Access and not SQL Server?

I thought it might related to using 64-bit vs 32-bit, so I tried adding a 32-bit ODBC as a Linked Server, but SQL Server would not allow me to.

Comment: Impossible to say without said query, but *"has about 20 sub-queries"* sounds like a contender already.

Comment: Yes. Not my query, but it does have to be done that way. Regardless, as I said in my post it works MS Access, so it should in SQL Server. Plus SQL is more than capable of handling that. So it's not the query.

Comment: Letting SQL Server do the job downloading the data via linked server must certainly by slower than letting the redshift database server do it with its local tables, as in the MS Access PassThrough-scenario. Btw: MS Access had nothing to do with the query processing. It sent the query to the server, let the server do the job and received the resulting rows.

Comment: Thanks wolfgang. Is there a way to get SQL Server to behave in a similar way?

Comment: So your tables are all in MS Access? Why would you expect querying via a SQL Server linked server to be faster?

Comment: As far as I know, the T-SQL equivalent of an Access pass-through query is to use [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you already have a Redshift ODBC driver and a working Redshift-native SQL query that you can invoke as an Access pass-through query then you might be able to use it in an OPENROWSET call from SQL Server. I tried something similar with a native PostgreSQL query [here](https://pastebin.com/rW9y6naU) and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the feedback I decided to scrap using Linked Sever and used SSIS instead to pull in the data. Thanks everyone for your time and help.